# Connecting Google Calendar with Django

Tags: django, integration, google-calendar-api

I've been trying to connect Google calendar with a Django app deployed on Google App Engine and though I've been following some of the other Stackoverflow answers- I'm still struggling with the problem as I need to connect OAuth2 independently. Could anyone please point me in the direction of a library that I could install it on my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "to connect OAuth2 independently" but I think you need [gdata-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) library and you can read about [how to use google calender API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html#auth) .

Comment: I tried using this library and have got it working on my computer through the python shell. I also managed to get it working on a Django application on my computer. But when I try to integrate that code in a Django application which is deployed on Google's app engine, I get errors saying that multiple modules - gflag, httplib2 cannot be found. Any tips?

Comment: Install all missing gdata dependancies to your deployment python enviroment.

Answer (score 2):

Google now have a basic Python starter app to download:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/get_started

It includes four libraries `apiclient`, `httplib2`, `oauth2client` and `uritemplate` in the download which you probably rather want to `pip install` and add to your project's requirements file instead.

EDIT
Actually even easier, you can just `pip install google-api-python-client`
it doesn't install anything except the four required libraries above, you then need to make some code like in `sample.py` downloaded from the 'get started' link.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python OAuth 2 library with info about integrating it with Django. Of course, it's currently a work-in-progress as OAuth 2 has not become a finalized RFC as of yet: https://github.com/dgouldin/python-oauth2